# fopen doesnt work with string parameter

Tags: c, fopen

i have a char matrix like below

```
char files[4][10];
```

And in the matrix these char arrays are hold.

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
```

when i try to use fopen with this matrix,i can not open the file.My code is this:

```
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen(files[0],"rb");

    if(file == NULL){
       printf("cannot open");
    }
    else printf("opened");
```

this code gives the output:cannot open.Where im doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Are the files in the same directory? 2) Did you check whether `files[0]` actually contains the correct string?

Comment: `printf("cannot open %s: %s\n", files[0], strerror(errno));` to find out why it failed and if `files[0]` contains what you believe.

Comment: yes it contains the correct file and they are in the same dir

Comment: @user1772101, it doesn't matter if the program binary and the files are in the same directory. It does matter that the program is executed in the same directory.

Comment: i read those file names from another file.Therefore i dont think the problem is that.

Comment: What is the error message you get when you use `printf` suggested by hmjd? Also try printing the filename in `printf` within quotes i.e. `printf ("Cannot open '%s' : %s\n", files[0], strerror(errno));` (You *may* need to include `errno.h` & `string.h`)

Comment: @user1772101, post more code. It is impossible to tell from the information available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things would come to mind:

- file1.txt is not available in the directory you call the executable
- You do not show how you initialize your files array. Might be that you are not 0 terminating the string.

Comment: i couldnt understand ur question properly but i add \n character at the end of every line of matrix.

Comment: @user1772101 That's your problem then, "0 terminating" means the final character should be `'\0'`. No linefeed.

Comment: i added \0 char at the end of every line but still doesnt work

Comment: Ehm, why have you accepted the answer? What worked? Please show some more code

Comment: @user1772101 don't accept those answer which doesn't solve the problem or doesn't belong to your question. Because, many other may face the same problem, if you will accept the wrong one. Then, that could be put them more trouble.